# MongoDB dealing with multiple objects with order field

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Let's imagine that there is some kind of presentation that contains many slides. Presentation collection in mongo could be represented like:

`{
  _id: <presentation_id>,
  author: <author_name>,
  ...
}`

And there is slides collection that contains slides for those presentations:

`{
  _id: <slide_id>,
  presentation_id: <presentation_id>,
  content: <content(html,text, etc.)>,
  order: <slide_order (page number)> /* This field is used to place slides in correct order during showcase*/
}`

Like in all presentation slides could be added, moved, removed, etc and it should autosave changes after each operation. With such scheme on every slide add or move we need to update a lot of slides with theirs order value. In meteor it leads to quiet large wait time (i.e. for presentation with 250 slides, if we add 1 slide into the beginning of it, we need to update 250 existed slides in `for` loop).

I also thought about 2 things how to deal with this:
1) Add to `presentation` new field `slides` that will be an array that contains slide ids in sequential order. But this way has problem with ordering: for now mongodb can't order results by array of ids (in <=2.4 versions there were a hack with using `$or`, but in 2.6 it no longer available) without using aggregation framework (which isn't present in meteor out of the box and requires additional modules). This will replace large amount of small updates with one big update.

2) Another way is to replace `order` field in slides collection with two new fields: `prev` and `next` and save only next and previous slide ids. This will reduce (re)move/add operations to few small updates, but when I need to show all slides, I'll need to do this in two steps: get slides form db in incorrect order, find first(last) slide and restore correct order using that next/prev "links".

What way is preferred? Or may by there is another better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would probably be to move the slides to a array in the presentation document.

Because in almost every use-case for the slides collection you will want the data from the presentation collection as well. A array is always ordered so you shouldn't need/require a _id field for the slide.

The only limit is that the total presentation document can not exceed 16megabytes.

You can then use mongodb's [array update modifiers](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update-array/) to move slides around in the collection. The [$position modifier](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/position/#up._S_position) is especially helpful for adding.
And you can combine [$splice and $push](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/slice/#use-slice-with-other-push-modifiers) for moving stuff around.

Edit: use $inc in you update for example:

**Inserting a slide in the middle of the order:**

```
 col.update({presentation_id:xxx, order:{$gte:20}},{$inc:{order:1}},{multi:true});
 col.insert({order:20, presentation_id:xxx/*otherdata*/});
```

This increments all the order fields starting from 20 so essentialy freeing up position 20. This uses mongos own cursor and not a for loop so should be a hell of a lot faster.

**Moving a document down:**

```
 var moveSlide = col.findOne({presentation_id:xxx, order:20});
 col.update({presentation_id:xxx, {order:{$lte:20}}},{$inc:{order:1}},{multi:true});
 col.update(moveSlide._id, {$set:{order:1}});
```

**Moving a document up:**

```
 var moveSlide = col.findOne({presentation_id:xxx, order:20});
 col.update({presentation_id:xxx, $and:[{order:{$lte:100}}, {order:{$gte:20}}]},{$inc:{order:-1}},{multi:true});
 col.update(moveSlide._id, {$set:{order:100}});
```

Comment: I've thought about this, but in our case there are a lot of presentations that could be just listed (without need of accessing to slides). And with this approach we will need 2 separate publishes for presentations with slide and without them (to avoid unnecessary overhead). And 16Mb limit is another reason why I didn't use it, because for now we have rather small presentations (images,files go to separate collection), but in future it can contain svg graphics or event base64 encoded images and this can cause serious limitations.

Comment: All worked. Thanks again. There were some mistakes in your code (for up and down):
Move item (`slide_id`) down (newPos > oldPos):
`Slides.update({pres_id: pres_id, _id:{$ne:slide_id}, $and: [{order: {$gte: oldPos}}, {order: {$lte: newPos}}]}, {$inc: {order: -1}}, {multi: true});`

Up: `Slides.update({pres_id: pres_id, _id:$ne:slide_id}, $and: [{order: {$lt: oldPos}},{order: {$gte: newPos}}]}, {$inc: {order: 1}}, {multi: true});`

When item moves down, order of items above `newPos` should decrease  and we also don't need to do anything with items below `newPos`, same with moving item up.